Elastic BeansStalk Health Status is showing Svere
My site where i hosted my web app is down. when I tried to to go to the site it shows 502 Bad Gateway.
so when I login to AWS and check the Elastic Beanstalk I discovered the health status is showing Severe in red, then I went to AWS cloud Watch and find the following information
awseb-e-ixmjranimv-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-1690RUPVZDFBY
Please can someone help.
Thank you.
Bala Y. Toro
I tried to check the network configuration of the ec2 but i could'nt find anything.

Why don't you try downloading the logs. A 502 error means a some issue with reaching your url. There's so many details missing. Is your app public or private? Are you using an http or https? You'll need to check from the vpc level if it's privately deployed.
